# To show Banach Operator Norm's equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am thinking the sentence which may be about the Banach algebra function:

Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ where $H$ is Hilbert. 
\begin{equation}
\| A \| = \sup_{ \| u \|, \| v \| \leq 1} | \langle Au, v \rangle |
\end{equation}

It is the norm but with continuous functions $u,v \in H$, I think. 
I am thinking which properties it holds to prove it. 
Apparently, completeness, continuity.

### My proposal

I think we need here the definition of the norm in Hilbert space i.e. vector's norm:
\begin{equation}
\|x\| = \sqrt{ \langle x, x \rangle }
\end{equation}
where I think the square root should be disappear through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality such that the operator norm equals the right-hand-side.

Let's consider $A$ is continuous, by provig the inequality
\begin{equation*}
| A | \leq M, \forall u,v \in H, \forall u,v \leq 1.
\end{equation*} 
Start with some $u \in H$. 
Note $u^{\pm} = |u| \pm u \in H$, so $u \geq 0$ so $\|A\| \geq 0$. 
So we get $| A | \leq M$, and since $u,v \leq 1$, we have the inequality. $\square$

Comments

- I really think that the proof of this statement should be more straight-forward. Cauchy-Schwarz should be enough but I have apparently mixed up some symbols in my attempt.
- I am not sure if the part starting from *A is continuous, by proving ...* is necessary for the proof.
- I am not sure about $u^{\pm}$. I tried to imply a similar proof of linear functionals from [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/2-06-b-cont.pdf#page=13).

---

How can you prove more rigorously the norm in Hilbert space?

Comment: I suspect you are missing a $\sup$ above. I presume $H$ is Hilbert?

Comment: So your question is how to prove the equality above? Also, what do you mean by "continuous variables"?

Comment: That link you have provided talks about the norm of a positive linear functional on $C_0(\Omega)$. What does that have to do with the norm of an operator on a Hilbert space?

Comment: Nothing. I went to side-tract.